# What the best way to convert from String to HashMap?

Tags: java, json, string, apache-commons-beanutils

I would like to serialize a Java HashMap to string representation. The HashMap will contains only primitive values like string and integer. After that this string will be stored to db. How to restore back the HashMap? 
Is it make sense to use BeanUtils and interface [Converter](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/Converter.html) or use JSON?

For example:

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(new Long(1));
    list.add(new Long(2));
    list.add(new Long(4)); 

    Map map = new HashMap();
    map.put("cityId", new Integer(1));
    map.put("name", "test");
    map.put("float", new Float(-3.2));
    map.put("ids", list);

    map.toString() -> {float=-3.2,ids=[1, 2, 4],name=test,cityId=1}
    map.toJSON ->     {"float":-3.2,"ids":[1,2,4],"name":"test","cityId":1}
```

Comment: Isn't this why people use Hibernate?

Comment: a list is not a primitive. Did you look at objectinputstream and objectoutputstream?

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON or [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/).

Comment: parsing xml is more expensive than JSON in this case

Answer (score 0):

Dr Jerry is correct, what you should do is serialize the hash map using ObjectOutputStream. This will let you write the bytes to a database BLOB type column and then you can de-serialize it back to your original object. To re-use a tired cliche, why re-invent the wheel? Is there a specific reason you don't want to use Java serialization in this case?

Comment: I don't want to serialize as a binary because it leads to different desertification issues and it's require use a BLOB type

Comment: Hmm, ok if using a BLOB is not feasible, then I like the JSON way as well, not the greatest, but works well. Google's GSON looks like it might do the trick for you. It supports java collections etc... check it out here:
http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide